Help on PID circuit design
I am trying to design an analog PID circuit. I am trying to understand the resetting part of the integrator stage. I have found the following circuit.

I am a bit puzzled by the AUTO-RESET part of the circuit.
To the left there is a Proportional stage and an integrator as wells as a derivative stage. I believe.
To the right, there is what I think is a window comparator, that compares the error input with VCCxR24/(R24+R25) and  VDDxR27/(R27+R26).
The part in the middle I do not understand, as I am not very experienced in the utilization of transistors.
Q: What is the point of D7, D8, Z1? When I add them to my LTSPICE simulation, the comparator does not work anymore (see below).
Q: Can I replace the transistors whose workings I do not understand very well with an analog switch like the ADG601?
Q: Why is the input of the comparator the error signal? Isn't the resetting part supposed to allow the integrator to reset after it has been saturated? Shouldn't therefore the resetting be conditioned on the output of the integrator?
Q (optional): What is the point of using  two capacitors C7/C8 with different polarities for the integrator instead of a single unpolarized one?
Comparator without diodes: 
Comparator with diodes: 


Q: What is the point of D7,D8,Z1. When I add them to my LTSPICE simulation, the comparator does not work anymore (see below).

It's inconclusive that your simulation isn't working. From what I see, it is working as I would expect with those values. You have to sweep the input voltage past the thresholds to see a change in the output.
D7 and D8 along with the comparators form an OR'ing function. Since the comparators can both sink and source current, they would short each other out with out the diode blocking function. Z1 is there to lower the operating point and properly bias Q4 such that it does not interfere with Q3. In other words, the idea is to have Q3 in the non-conducting state during normal (non-resetting) operation so that C7 and C8 can perform the integration while not being shorted out.

Q: Can I replace the transistors whose workings I do not understand very well with an analog switch like the ADG601?

Sure, but the circuitry would have to be modified to accommodate that change. Understanding the behavior of the transistors in this case is quite simple. Q3 is acting as a switch that is "off" for normal integration operation. Q4 and the discretes around it are the interfacing circuitry - the comparators can't control Q3 directly.

Q: Why is the input of the comparator the error signal? Isn't the resetting part supposed to allow the integrator to reset after it has been saturated? Shouldn't therefore the resetting be conditioned on the output of the integrator?

It is, but it's happening indirectly. Imaging that the output is starting to approach saturation. The (process value - the setpoint), or error will increase from the integrator "winding up". At some point governed by the comparators, it will be determined that the process is no longer controlled due to the integrator error. This triggers one of the comparators to reset the integrator caps.
In normal, well controlled, operation; the difference of the process variable and set point are very small (error = 0) implying that the control is still in regulation.

Q (optional): What is the point of using two capacitors C7/C8 with different polarities for the integrator instead of a single unpolarized one?

The integrating capacitors can be charged with either polarity depending on the error. Putting two polarized caps back-to-back provides you with a large, unpolarized equivalent capacitor. A single, unpolarized capacitor is actually 2 unpolarized capacitors in one package. But it's typically represented as one capacitor on the circuit.

Hi, would you agree in saying that when the PID starts its job, for example the first time it is turned on, the error can be very big (for example the setpoint is 10V and the error as big as 10V), in this case the integrator won't do anything, it will only start working when the error gets small?  Also in this example doesn't the integrator output go to 0 directly when the switch is on ? isn't that going to cause a jump in the output of the servo? isn't that bad? isn't it better if the output of the integrator stays constant when it reaches a certain value fixed by the comparator?

Also, I've really been trying  to understand the Or'ing thing, but every time I try to follow the logic of the circuit I get that it is and AND gate not an OR gate, when you said OR'ing function was that a general term you were using or am I really incorrect? Thank you a lot

@DarkBulle What happens when the circuit is first turned on is not well defined - that would be a transient analysis. I've described the steady-state behavior after all the voltage and currents fall into appropriate values for the components. Yes, the integrator function is disabled when the error is large (positive or negative). There won't be a jump in the output because the integration changes slowly over time (I believe you're thinking of the behavior of the differentiator in which rapid changes on input cause large voltage swings on output).

@DarkBulle OR'ing, the way I'm presenting the logic, is if the upper OR lower comparator is active. However, active is LOW state. Flipping the logic (see DeMorgan's theorem) to the active state would be both comparators output high (AND) for integration. So, it could be either depending how you define the logic. The reason I went with active low state logic is it is very common to use "open-collector" comparators to provide the OR'ing function. And that's exactly what's being done here. The only difference is the diodes cause the comp outputs are totem pole, not open collector/drain.

The C7&C8 form an nonpolarised capacitor from polarised ones. It is because nonpolarised caps are few uF available only.
The D7&D8 form an AND gate, i.e. both comparators have to be high to switch on the Q4.
Sure you can replace Jfet with analog switch. Two optocouplers agains each other for simple caps discharging are usable also.
